# How do you "hide" games you do not own or demos?

Tags: psn, playstation-plus

In the PlayStation 4 library, I got free DLC for a game I don't own but I want to hide it until I buy it. If so, is there is a way to do that with demos too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no. Many people have been requesting this. At least they gave us folders to help sort the items we do have installed, and they eventually allowed us to delete 0% games from our trophy lists, so there is hope that they will address this issue as well.

Comment: Hey Bryan!  You might want to add how to create folders as an option to hide unwanted apps! :)

Comment: I can add that but it doesn't provide a solution for the question which is how to hide them from the Library. Folders do not do that. They only apply to installed items on the launch bar.